# Bye KEEP DENSE_RANK?

Tags: oracle, fetch

With data given

> Id       sdate               sales
>
> 1     15.03.2015           150
>
> 2     16.03.2015            170

where id+date is unique combination 
one could easily find the best date, or best item to sale.
`Select max(date) keep(dense_rank last order by sales) from data`.

So far so good. But suppose we have data like following:

> Id      sdate               sales
>
> 1     15.03.2015          150
>
> 2     16.03.2015          170
>
> 1     15.03.2015          117
>
> 2     16.03.2015           97

… some other dates with worst sale sums than 15.03.2015 and 16.03.2015

Now I want to know the best DATES to sale

`Select max(sdate) keep(dense_rank last order by sum(sales)) from data group by sdate`.
Hey! It shows only 15.03.2015. But I want to see it both – 15.03.2015 and 16.03.2015.
LISTAGG doesn’t help here too. Only

```
Select sdate from data group by sdate
Order by sum(sales) DESC  FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
```

Returns me both dates. So, bye KEEP DENSE_RANK? Meet FETCH FIRST?
What is your opinion , respective all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... whether you should completely stop using `keep dense rank` even when it is appropriate, because you can get the same result with `fetch first`? Or are you not sure how to get both dates without `fetch first` (i.e. before 12c)?

Answer (score 0):

They're doing different things. [`keep`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions065.htm) can only return one row for each group. As you want to see tied values, you can't use `keep`, but you could do this with an inline view:

```
select sdate
from (
  select sdate, dense_rank() over (order by sum(sales) desc) as rnk
  from data
  group by sdate
)
where rnk = 1;
```

Which is essentially what `fetch first rows with ties` is doing in 12c in this example.

There are situations where `keep` is appropriate, and others where an inline view or `fetch first rows` is appropriate, and some where either would work.

Having a scenario where you can't use `keep` to get the result you want doesn't mean you should *never* use it. Your first simpler query could use either approach; if you wanted other information then `keep` would come into its own (like the examples in the documentation for `first`). There are a lot of tools available and you need to pick the best one for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Andrew - Oracle 12c uses an inline view under the hood anyway (see the bottom [of this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-sep/o53asktom-1999186.html)), the `fetch first` is just 'syntactic sugar'. And `keep dense rank` has never been able to do what you want it to here. I'm still not sure what you're getting at I'm afraid, as you're comparing different tools for different tasks.

Comment: Alex, I mean to do things in one select without any sub-queries... In the very first example, where id+sdate are unique combination I can write 
`select min(listagg(sdate,';') within group(order by sdate)) keep(dense_rank first order by sale_sum desc) group by sales`

And things are differ if i have more than one sale per date and still want to have a ONE select to catch 'em all

`select min(listagg(sdate,';') within group(order by sdate)) keep(dense_rank first order by sum(sales) desc) group by sdate` fails.
A magic phrase inside `keep(dense_rank`,say  `with ties` would be helpful

Comment: And, Alex thanks for link. Tom Kyte is great , as usually